# Scroll function not seeing whole page

Tags: javascript, audio, triggers, scroll

I'm having some issues with my $(window).on('scroll', function(){}
My code is only ever seeing the first of several triggers on the page.

On the site there are triggers of audio that, when on screen, need to turn the track on while turning the previous one off. The triggers are like this throughout the page:

```
<audio class="atmos" id="pubAtmos" controls><source src="audio/pubAtmos.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

The code for the scroll function is:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) 
{
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}


$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.atmos').each(function(){
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this)) {
            for (i=0 ; i < atmosArray.length ; i++){
                if (this.id == atmosArray[i].id) {
                    this.play();
                }
                else if (this.id != atmosArray[i].id) {
                    atmosArray[i].paused();
                }
            }
        }
    }
)});
```

All the audio id's relate to the atmosArray id's so I can control them with the for loops, my brain is stuck in a loop of coding things that just turn off what it's also starting.
The only one that is playing currently is the first one.
Is there a better way I should be going through to find the match and playing/pausing?

Comment: have you tried using a breakpoint and debugging?

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that the condition fails, yet you're not posting the `isScrolledIntoView` function ?

Comment: I've just added it. The function is picking up the class, so that bits working. I think it's just the else if statement I have wrong...I guess I prematurely titled the post wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is your "this" is not what you think it is.  You should define a variable for your each function like this:

```
$('.atmos').each(function(that){
```

and then use "that" instead of "this" in the rest of the code.

BTW: you don't need the condition after the else.  Just "else" will do fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I've been trying to understand the "this" call in javascript and must have missed something. Though it does get the right id as I scroll down the page. I haven't come across the "that" variable before, do I need to declare it somewhere else, or just in the '.each(function(){'

Comment: It's not a special variable like "this".  It's just a variable to hold the reference in the each statement.  If "this" is working for you then fine, but I try to avoid it if I can get a more direct reference.